# How to grep top most frequent error messages in a unix logfile

Tags: linux, shell, grep, webserver

If I have a file example apache log file

How to extract the top most frequent error messages in a unix log file with no timestamps

the key is most frequent error message should come on top of the list

Comment: `grep message logfile | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | head`

Comment: Sorry, `head` should read `tail`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, more clearly defining the question; Ursadon has answered it for you, so could you please accept his or her answer so we can stop this question popping up again?  As you will gather by the slowly-accumulating downvotes, this question is arguably off-topic for SF.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/474059/3013944) there is a nice answer. I think it is suitable for many logs without any modification. They recommend to grep errors first, preparing significantly smaller logfile for analysis `grep -vi -e 'info' -e 'warn'`

Answer (score 12):

`cat /tmp/file`:

```
ERROR 1 1234
ERROR 2 1234
ERROR 3 1234
ERROR 4 1234
ERROR 4 1234
ERROR 3 1234
ERROR 2 1234
ERROR 5 1234
ERROR 1 1234
ERROR 4 1234
ERROR 1 1234
ERROR 1 1234
ERROR 1 1234
ERROR 3 1234
ERROR 2 1234
ERROR 1 1234
ERROR 4 1234
ERROR 1 1234
ERROR 4 1234
ERROR 1 1234
ERROR 2 1234
```

`grep "ERROR" /tmp/file | sort | uniq -c | sort -r`:

```
  8 ERROR 1 1234
  5 ERROR 4 1234
  4 ERROR 2 1234
  3 ERROR 3 1234
  1 ERROR 5 1234
```

first column shows how many occurrences of each string were found
Explanation:

```
grep "ERROR" /tmp/file\ # select only ERROR string
| sort\ # order
| uniq -c\ #  count duplicate items
| sort -rn # reverse order and use numeric sort
```

for top 5 errors, you can add `|head -n5`

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to chop off timestamp to get unique error

grep 'error message' /logfiles | cut -d' ' -f6- | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in "sorting" all you system.log errors by a specific **date + time** too?

**try: (for date only search)**

```
grep -i "Jul 18" /var/log/*.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

**try: (for for a specific *date + time* search)**

```
grep -i "Jul 18 16:" /var/log/*.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

NOTE: for a specific date first do a cat *.log and then look for what the header says it might be different depending on the O/S.  The above example is for UNIX/MacOS and you have to "manually" edit the "Jul 18 16:" with what it says in your "cat /var/log/system.log" header for your particular O/S.

Hope this helps!

:)